# How to fetch the documents where the field in array is not equal to particular value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Documents in database collection are in below format

```
{
  _id:1,
  a: [{b:1, c:2, d:3}, {b:2, c:3, d:4}]
},
{
  _id:2,
  a: [{b:2, c:2, d:4}, {b:3, c:5, d:4}]
},
{
  _id:3,
  a: [{b:4, c:4, d:3}, {b:5, c:3, d:2}]
}
```

From the above documents I need to get only the documents where 'b!=4' that means only _id=1 & _id=2 should be returned.

For this I have tried the below query but I didn't get the expected result. Instead I got all documents.

```
db.collectionname.find({a: {$nin: [{b: 4}]}})
```

Any alternate solution, please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're using the wrong operator. You should use **`$ne`** instead of `**$nin**`.

From [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/):

> $nin selects the documents where:
>
> - the field value is not in the specified array 
>     or
> - the field does not exist.

so the query

```
db.collectionname.find({a: {$nin: [{b: 4}]}})
```

will look for document with array `a` not containing this exact document: `{b: 4}` . Here the 3 documents match because inner documents has `b` and `c` keys, wheras `{b: 4}` hasn't.

For a single field check, you should use [**`$ne`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/)

The correct query is

```
db.collectionname.find({"a.b": {$ne: 4}})
```

This returns:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "a" : [ { "b" : 1, "c" : 2, "d" : 3 }, { "b" : 2, "c" : 3, "d" : 4 } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "a" : [ { "b" : 2, "c" : 2, "d" : 4 }, { "b" : 3, "c" : 5, "d" : 4 } ] }
```

Comment: Can we possibly add a sentence or two to explain that the perception of using `$nin` or `$in` in order to match an array is actually "the other way around", since it is those operators that take the "list of values" rather than "matching against a list". Considering the OP jumped to `$nin` it might be nice to actually explain "why" their choice was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation too, Now I understood the difference.